# Record count for sent data view object is different in query editor & tracking extract

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, data-views

We are using tracking extract API to extract data views from the Marketing cloud. We get ~382 records when we extract sent object using this. However, when same object is queried we get ~25k records in query studio. Is the difference because of business unit associated with the user or there is some other reason?

Query I am executing in query studio -

```sql
select 
  AccountId
, OYBAccountID
, JobId
, ListId
, BatchId
, SubscriberId
, SubscriberKey
, Eventdate
, Domain
, TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
, TriggeredSendCustomerKey 
from _Sent
```

Below is my tracking extract SOAP request-

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>#username#</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>#password#</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ExtractRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Requests>
        <ID>c7219016-a7f0-4c72-8657-1ec12c28a0db</ID>
        <Parameters>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>OutputFileName</Name>
            <Value>dataview_Sent_2021102806310525600.zip</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>StartDate</Name>
            <Value>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>EndDate</Name>
            <Value>2021-10-28T06:31:05Z</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>Format</Name>
            <Value>csv</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ColumnDelimiter</Name>
            <Value>Default</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>CharacterEncoding</Name>
            <Value>Default</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>QuoteText</Name>
            <Value>true</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>TextQualifier</Name>
            <Value>"</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>UnicodeOutput</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>Timezone</Name>
            <Value>1</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>UseIDs</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>UseLocalTZinQuery</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>IncludeUserAgentInformation</Name>
            <Value>true</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>IncludeAllListMembers</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>IncludeAllSubscribers</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>IncludeInferredOpens</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>IncludeMilliseconds</Name>
            <Value>true</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>IncludeTestSends</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>IncludeUnsubReason</Name>
            <Value>true</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ExtractClicks</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ExtractBounces</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ExtractClickImpressions</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ExtractConversions</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>extractListMembershipChanges</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>extractLists</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ExtractNotSent</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ExtractOpens</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ExtractSendImpressions</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ExtractSendJobImpressions</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ExtractSendJobs</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ExtractSent</Name>
            <Value>true</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>extractStatusChanges</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ExtractSurveyResponses</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ExtractSpamComplaints</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>ExtractUnsubs</Name>
            <Value>false</Value>
          </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
      </Requests>
    </ExtractRequestMsg>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the options you've configured in your tracking extract activity.

Comment: ...or the details of the API call you're using to retrieve tracking data.

Comment: Can you also include the query you're executing in Query Studio?

Comment: What happens when you set _sent.OYBAccountID to your MID in your query?  I don't see you specifying the ClientID in your Tracking Extract call either.  Both of those impact the BU scope of what's returned.

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs, I am getting same result.